# Can sitemap.xml be in another path different than the root path (/)?

Tags: seo

Before starting to create my sitemap file I wanted to take a look at the sitemaps of a few webpages that I know (online shops, blogs, ....).
For my surprise, 100% of them do not have a sitemap.xml (I just checked the root path: domain/sitemap.xml). After that, several doubts surged to me.

What could be the reason for that?

Do they have their sitemap.xml in another path/name? I understand that could be possible, but I suspect that is not advised.

Don't they have a sitemap at all? In that case, sitemaps would not be as important as I initially thought because these webpages have an important amount of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

A sitemap can be anywhere on the site and can be any name.  It is specified in **robots.txt**.

For instance, look at [GMail](https://gmail.com/robots.txt)

> User-agent: *
>
> Allow: /
>
> Disallow: /a/*
>
> Disallow: /mail?hl=*
>
> Disallow: /tasks/*
>
> Sitemap: https://www.google.com/gmail/sitemap.xml